# Add hidden field to form

Tags: php, html

I generate HTML form with as follows:

```
<tr class=orm id=tr8>
    <td class=form_rowtitle><div id=row8a>Name</div></td>
    <td>
    <div id=edit8>  
    <input id=input8 type=text size=30>
    </div>
    <div id=saved8></div>
    </td>
    <td><div id=error8></div></td>
</tr>
```

and retrieve the entered value with `$value=$_POST['saved8'];`
I am confused on how to add a hidden field here and on how to retrieve the hidden field data.
Please help, I've tried following:

```
<input type=hidden name=token value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type=hidden id=token value='XYZ' />
```

But unable to retrieve.

Comment: What value are you getting with - `$value=$_POST['saved8'];`? there are no fields with that name and no forms also.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have a space in the name html attribute.
once you have a single word name for example token_value you can access it the same way: `$token_value=$_POST['token_value'];`

so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token_value" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="XYZ" />
<?php
$token_value=$_POST['token_value'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
?>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it doesn't work..please check the working code on how the id(saved8) is defined

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually a form send data to PHP using a POST or GET variable, and as I see you are using POST. In order to retrieve data from a field in a form you should use the *name* attribute.

```
<input type=hidden id=token value='XYZ' name=tokenName /> in the form.

$token = $_POST['tokenName']; in the PHP file.
```